# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int

Tags: sql-server, errors, type-conversion

```
declare @targetnumber int 
declare @numberfield varchar(20) = 'stepnum' 
declare @sourcetable varchar(20) = 'tblsteps' 
declare @idfield varchar(20) = 'stepid' 
declare @recid int = 3

set @TargetNumber = 
    'SELECT ' +  @NumberField +  
    ' FROM ' + @sourcetable +
    ' WHERE ' + @idfield + ' = ' + @recid

select @targetnumber as MyTargetNumber
```

> ```
> ERROR:  Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 
> 'SELECT stepnum FROM tblsteps WHERE stepid = ' to data type int.
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a step. You are dynamically generating a string that represents your select statement, but you aren't executing it and returning the value to @targetnumber, you're just trying to set @targetnumber (an int) to the value of that string. The string concatenation fails because @recid (also an int) must first be changed into a compatible data type, such as varchar(11).

To visualize what is really happening in your example, temporarily declare @targetnumber as varchar(1000) and @recid as varchar(11) and re-run the example.

What you'll want to look into is [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#return-code-values) or other [methods of executing dynamically generated SQL](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/).

Answer (score 2):

Try converting the `@recid` (has data type `int`) to `varchar` data type

```
set @TargetNumber = 'SELECT ' +  @NumberField + 
     ' FROM ' + @sourcetable +
     ' WHERE ' + @idfield + ' = ' + CAST(@recid AS varchar(20))
```

When you combine expressions with different data types, there are some rules for converting, from lower to higher precedence.

- `int` = data type is at position 16
- `varchar` data type is at position 27

See [Data type precedence (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in the product documentation.

Also, be aware of [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

### Later edit:

as suggested by @sp_BlitzErik, the next problem will be

```
set @TargetNumber =
```

because @TargetNumber it is `int` data type, and you will have the same problem/error , different message : `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SELECT stepnum FROM tblsteps WHERE stepid = 3' to data type int.`

This time, you need to change in declaretion section to :

`declare @targetnumber varchar(500)`

dbfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=18d859c272f07834f9977597d0aa6d77)

Comment: I think the problem is that they expect to set @targetnumber to the result of the dynamic query.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik , you are also right; The error posted is related to @ recid been int. Once this solved , john will have another error  related to @ targetnumber